# How might I call a JavaScript Function in a Page Viewed by a WebBrowser Control from the Application Hosting the WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I've created a C# Desktop Application which depends on web crawler idea.

I made my application using web browser control to open a website and login progmatically and redirect to the specific page which have a gridview with all user's data  that I want to collect...

But the issue here username in the gridview click fired by JavaScript function. I know its name but not how to call it inside desktop application.

What are the namespaces or DLLs that would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 8):

I think this should help you out:

http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/493536.aspx

**EDIT:** Based on that link, here's a small sample app. Add a Button and a WebBrowser control to a Windows Form and add this code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<html>
<body>
<script type = ""text/javascript"">
function ShowMessage(text) {
   alert(text);
}
</script>
</body>
<input type=""button"" onclick=""ShowMessage('From JavaScript')"" value=""Click me""/>
</html>";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("ShowMessage",new object[]{"From C#"});
        }
    }
```

If you click the button in the browser, it'll show the javascript message, if you click the button in the windows form, it'll show the C# message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of just using the following to run script on page using `WebBrowser` control?

```vb
' In VB - but easy to convert to C# as its pretty much the same thing :).
Dim sScript As String, sLanguage As String
sLanguage = "JScript"
sScript = "MyJavaScriptToRun();" ' you can run many lines by delimiting them with ;

WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript sScript, sLanguage
```

Let me know how you get along. In the .NET versions of the `WebBrowser` control, there are additional methods to run script, I think there is a `.RunScript` type method (can't recall exact name but you will notice it once you see it in intellisense).

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Can you just use C# then? Do you even know C#?

Comment: @xiaomao Can you not read the above code? The only difference is the Dim, which is declaration of sScript and sLanguage, the rest is the same as C# as long as you place a ; at the end of each line. Do you need help interpreting the above?